# OSError: OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found - osm2geojson for Python

Tags: python, windows

I installed osm2geojson with Anaconda following these instructions:https://pypi.org/project/osm2geojson/

Now, every time when I try to import osm2geojson into my Jupyter notebook I receive the following error message:
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

All my attempts to find a working solution failed.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: In general we like to see the actual code not a picture of it - makes it easier to read for us older users :-)

Comment: Hi, so what I did is:
1)  install osm2geojson using "pip install osm2geojson"
2) What I want to do is convert some JSON data I retrieved from OSM, using an Overpass API, and convert it into GeoJSON so I can store it to my computer to further analyse it with ArcGIS
3) I tried to install pip-python3 install openslide-python, as this was suggested as a solution for this particular error code, but I cannot install this package; it gives me error message that the version couldn't be found